# When do we need quoted lists in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I have just started with Clojure, its been just a week.
I tried solving some standard problems the Clojure way.

I read about quoted lists, that don't get evaluated and are considered a standard collection of data like vectors.

What are the scenarios where a quoted form of a list will be useful instead of vectors ?

Comment: Apart from a list built by `cons`-ing stuff I can't think of many. Mostly you don't have to worry about this yourself though.

Answer (score 3):

Macros and literal list instantiation. In macros you usually need syntax quote instead of normal quote

- http://clojure.org/macros
- http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Learning_Clojure/Macros
- http://techbehindtech.com/2010/09/28/clojure-macros-simplified/

Answer (score 2):

Clojure lists can be used as immutable, persistent singly-linked lists. For typical list operations, especially those involving head and tail manipulation, lists will perform much better than vectors. Additionally, the quoted form of a list doesn't get immediately evaluated, so you can store function calls in them and control when the calls are executed; do the same thing in a vector, and everything would run immediately in sequence.

Vectors are better for random access, and they perform better if you need to append data to the end of the collection. They are also "associative", which means that you can treat them as maps where the key is the index of the value, and you can use them for transient operations (which is a whole other topic).